# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running in 2012R2, mouse react slowly

Tags: hyper-v

i'n nwe in Linux, I'm trying Ubuntu in hyper-v. I feel the mouse react slowly, I have another systems running and I feel run better.

It's like Ubuntu needs something as "integration services" .

Thanks everybody.